# Different/Same data in coreData

Tags: objective-c, select, core-data, entity-relationship

I have three entities SchoolClass, teacher, subject. Entities looks as follows:

**SchoolClass**

[image: SchoolCLass]

**Subject**

[image: Subject]

**ClassTeacher**

[image: ClassTeacher]

Example: I have 3 classes - 2.A, 3.C, 4.D. Two teachers Mr.Smith, Mr.Brown. And three subject English, Math, Biology. 
Now I need to save this information. Class 2.A has two subject: Math,Biology and 3.C has also this subjects + English, so I do something like this (I use only pseudo-code):

*class2A.subjects = {"Math", "Biology"}*

*class3C.subjects = {"Math","Biology",English}*

Farther know, that Mr.Smith teach two classes: 2.A, 3.C:

*MrSmith.schoolClasses = {"2.A","3C"}.*

Its simple and clear. But I know, that Mr.Smith teach in 2.A Math and Biology. And I need to save this information: Who learn Math in 2.A and which subjects teach Mr.Smith in 2.A.
Please how can I do it?
I just though one option, but I don't know if is possible.

Can I do this for set the data?Also pseudo-code (I'm new in objective-c and I don't know how write it exactly in code)

*MrSmith.setOfSchollClasses[2.A].subjects = {"Math", "Biology"}*

*2.A.setOfSubjects[Math].setOfTeachers = {"Mr.Smith"}*

It is possible? How can I get data, who teach in 2.A Math and which subjects teach Mr.Smith in 2.A?

Comment: Yes, it's possible.  First, though, you're going to need to know Objective-C and how to use it to interact with CoreData.  `NSPredicate` is key to selecting things based on their content and relationships.

Comment: I did only basic operations (not relationships), but I wanted to know if my model is correct and applicable to what I need.